# angular js directive not loading array from web service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to link an array to a directive but the data is not showing up. The data comes in through a webservice callout when the page loads:

```
var profile = angular.module('profile.controllers', []);


profile.directive('propertyRow', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/partials/propRow.ejs',
        scope: {
            displayProps : "="
        },
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                console.log('clicked a property');
            });
        }
    };
});


profile.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window',  function($scope, $http, $window){
    var landlord_id = my_user;
    $scope.properties = [];
    $scope.landlord_id = landlord_id

    $http.get('/api/getPropsByLandlord/' + landlord_id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.properties = data;
        })
```

......

The html for the directive:

```
<property-row display-props="properties"></property-row>
```

Template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="property in displayProps">
  <td>{{property.name}}</td> 
</tr>
```

If the template is `<p>hello</p>` then it works fine so I assume it has something to do with the load.

Comment: It looks like you havent connected the scope of your controller to the scope of your directive. Try following the controller definitions laid out here: http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/

Comment: @Oleg it looks like he is setting the local scope value `displayProps` of his directive to the `properties` model in the controller. All he is missing is a connection between the two. I am putting together a complete answer.

Comment: @dopatraman It seems so. Go for it.

Comment: Everything looks like it should be working to me. Are you sure the get request is not producing an error? Try putting an .error handler after your .success handler.

Comment: it isn't... i have an error handler and i logged the success... it's all good.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the scope.$apply to ensure my directive was receiving the data

```
$.get('/api/getPropsByLandlord/' + my_user)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        $scope.properties = data;
                    });
                })
```

Comment: Ah, that would work as well. the source of the problem was latency between the completion of the first $digest and the loading of your directive's data. Nice work.

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like my original assumption about the link between controller and directive was wrong. The scope value you have tied to the controller (`displayProps` -> `properties`) is done properly. The problem seems to lie in a latency condition between the loading of the page and the loading of the directive. Your speculation about the load may have been correct.

Change your controller to the following:

```
profile.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$window',  function($scope, $http, $window){
 var landlord_id = my_user;
    $scope.properties = [];
    $scope.landlord_id = landlord_id

    $http.get('/api/getPropsByLandlord/' + landlord_id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.properties = data;
        })

    $scope.$watch('properties', function(val) {
      $scope.properties = val;
    })
}]);
```

and it should work. Take a look at this plunkr for an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/e6ktJtUMWqhwfYdI9yaL?p=preview

i didnt replicate your http request because I am confident it is not the source of the problem. Angular's digest cycle loads the page and then the directives. If there is a value in the directive scope it will not be caught by the first digest loop, so you must watch the value and trigger a new digest loop when it changes.

Read more about angular's digest loop here: http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/